# Android, how to use coordinator layout with bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I have a problem using coordinator layout with bottom navigation bar, the fragment container appear to be under the bottom navigation bar.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I arrange the elements to create the fragment container between the top app bar and bottom navigation view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been 10 months ago, i think it's kinda late to answer

i just face the same problem... To solve it you need to wrap your coordinatorLayout inside constraintLayout, like this:

```
<constraintLayout>

    <coordinatorLayout>
        <AppBarLayout>
        </AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout>
    </coordinatorLayout>

    <BottomNavigatioNView>
</constraintLayout>
```

this is the example of mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary_900"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_home"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary_900"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and make sure you set width and height of CoordinatorLayout to 0dp.
Hope it helpful.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTw0R.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY0zi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap whole layout with `LinearLayout` and set it's property orientation to `vertical`. Than Move `AppBar` and `BottomNavigation` outside of CoordinatorLayout.

Your widget tree should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Appbar/>
    <CoordinatorLayout/>
    <BottomNavigation/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of CoordinatorLayout you can use ConstraintLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/homeToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"/>
   <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is needed to coordinate top app bar and scroll content.

Comment: I think the best approach might be to implement a custom behavior that handles anchoring with the bottom, does anyone know where to start?